# What was Audrey's expected endgame before things took a dark turn?

Tags: plot-explanation, something-wild-1986

In the 1986 movie [Something Wild](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091983/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) Charles (played by Jeff Daniels) a relatively boring office worker is seduced/kidnapped by "Lulu" (who is actually Audrey, played by Melanie Griffiths) for some wild scheme she has cooked up which initially involves a seduction, a motel room and handcuffs). She later takes him to visit her mother and her High School reunion while pretending he is her husband. Then things go dark when her actual husband turns up having been released from jail unexpectedly.

Before the dark, violent turn when her ex-husband turns up (which she didn't expect) what was Audrey's plan and how did she expect her shenanigans to end?

Comment: From what I can read, she has none. She's just an agent of chaos doing what she wants.

Comment: @Paulie_D She cleary is that agent of chaos. The question is *what* does she want?

Comment: Why does she need to want anything...she's just going with the flow? Regardless, I don't think there is a definitive answer here.

Comment: @Paulie_D You might be right that no meaningful answer can exist. But the movie up to the point where the husband appears has more than just "going with the flow" and seems to have at least *part* of a coherent plan.